# How to Sync 6 Laptops in network in MS Access 2010 Application with Split database

Tags: ms-access-2010

i created an Application build in MS Access 2010, this create Jobs Orders, I am using split database which let me keep the tables in the server and the Front end program in the Work Station. Now, the problem is i have 6 laptops with the same application, but when the go out to the field the Laptops disconnect from network. I NEED A WAY TO SYNC TABLES WITH THE JOBS DONE when laptops come back to the office and connect to the network again.

I am Syncing pressing a button that copy files to server, delete tables locally and then copy back from server the records, but i want to find a way to Sync automatic when laptops find the network.

```
'*************IN THIS PART AM SENDING UPDATING SERVER AND SENDING NEW RECORDS ************
Dim x As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim strSQL As String

x = MsgBox("Are you Sure you want to Send to Server?????", vbOKCancel, "Are you sure?")
If x = vbOK Then
Dim intX, intY As Integer
Dim intW As Integer
Dim db As Database
Dim LSQL, SOurce, DestinaTion, fILE As String
Dim FSO

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

SOurce = "O:\fieldticket\"
'DestinaTion = "\\rvfile03\Departments\Water\Common\FieldTickets\"
DestinaTion = "\\rwmain01\gis\FieldTicket\"
fILE = Dir$(SOurce & "*.one")
'    Do While Len(fILE) > 0 And FSO.FileExists(DestinaTion & fILE) = True
Do While Len(fILE) > 0
    If FSO.FileExists(fILE & DestinaTion) = False Then
        FileCopy SOurce & fILE, DestinaTion & fILE
    End If
    fILE = Dir$()
Loop

fILE = Dir$(SOurce & "*.pdf")
Do While Len(fILE) > 0
    If FSO.FileExists(fILE & DestinaTion) = False Then
        FileCopy SOurce & fILE, DestinaTion & fILE
    End If
    fILE = Dir$()
Loop

Set db = CurrentDb()

'  REINIT PROGRESS BAR
ProgressBarB.WIDTH = 0
Me.Repaint
' FILL IN OUR SQL QUERIES COLLECTION
   Define_SQL_Queries

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Me.Refresh
Me.Repaint

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Me.Refresh
    With CurrentDb
        '    ******* COUNT HOW MANY NEW RECORD ARE TRANSFERING **************************************************
        intX = DCount("*", "RECORDS IN JobsOrder NOT IN JobsOrder1")

        ' ********** UPDATE JOBSORDER TABLE AND COUNT HOW MANY RECORDS ARE UPDATED ******************************
        LSQL = "UPDATE_Jobsorder1_SERVER_WITH_Jobsorder"
        db.Execute LSQL

        ' ****************  GIVE A MESSAGE OF HOW MANY RECORDS ARE UPDATED AND TRANSFERED **********************
        MsgBox CStr(db.RecordsAffected) & " RECORDS UPDATED " & intX & " NEW RECORDS WILL BE ADDED AND "

        '************ new progress bar code using for command *************
        Me.ProgressBarA.Visible = True
        Me.ProgressBarB.Visible = True
        For i = 1 To colSQL.Count
            strSQL = colSQL(i)
            Debug.Print "Executing : " & strSQL
            Call .QueryDefs(strSQL).Execute
            ProgressBarB.WIDTH = (ProgressBarA.WIDTH / colSQL.Count) * i
            Me.Repaint
        Next i
        Call Me.Requery
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End With

'    MsgBox ("TRANSFER AND UPDATE HAS BEEN FINISHED!!!")
Me.ProgressBarA.Visible = False
Me.ProgressBarB.Visible = False
'    Exit Sub
ElseIf x = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub
End If

    '*******NOW I AM SENDING BACK FROM SERVER TO HANDHELD ************************

Dim y As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Dim strSQL1, SOurce1, DestinaTion1, fIL1E As String

Beep
'x = MsgBox("Are you Sure you want to UPDATE HANDHELD?????", vbOKCancel, "Are you sure?")
'If y = vbOK Then
 'If PASSWORD = "222222" Then
    Dim intX1, intY1 As Integer
    Dim intW1 As Integer

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

ProgressBarB.WIDTH = 0
Me.Repaint

    'SOurce = "\\rvfile03\Departments\Water\Common\FieldTickets\"
    'DestinaTion = "c:\mapping\"
    'fILE = Dir$(SOurce & "*.one")
    'Do While Len(fILE) > 0
    '    If Dir$(fILE) & "" = "" Then
    '        FileCopy SOurce & fILE, DestinaTion & fILE
    '    End If
    '    fILE = Dir$()
    'Loop


    ' FILL IN OUR SQL QUERIES COLLECTION
     Define_SQL_Queries1

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    Me.Refresh
        With CurrentDb
            intX1 = DCount("*", "RECORD IN Jobsorder1 not Finished")
'             MsgBox (intX1 & " RECORDS WILL BE ADDED")


        Me.ProgressBarA.Visible = True
        Me.ProgressBarB.Visible = True
        For ii = 1 To colSQL1.Count
            strSQL1 = colSQL1(ii)
            Debug.Print "Executing : " & strSQL1
            Call .QueryDefs(strSQL1).Execute
            ProgressBarB.WIDTH = (ProgressBarA.WIDTH / colSQL1.Count) * ii
            Me.Repaint
        Next ii
        Call Me.Requery
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End With
MsgBox ("HANDHELD UPDATE COMPLETED!!!"), vbInformation
ProgressBarA.Visible = False
ProgressBarB.Visible = False
Exit Sub
'ElseIf y = vbCancel Then
'    Exit Sub
'End If
 MsgBox (intX1 & " RECORDS ADDED TO HANDHELD")


'******** FINISHING THE HANADHEL UPDATING *******************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write some code to check connectivity (On Error Resume next when connecting to the back end tables and check for an Error) and then connect to another local table if offline. Then once back in the office that code can then connect as normal and then you can upload your Jobs. Bottom line is that it'll take some VBA to do this. I can't give you a solution in code but this is the gist of it.

If you know how to code in VBA then you can really just check for a Network Folder that will be there if you're on the network. If it's not there, then you can assume you're offline. Then you will need to write more code to deal with local tables rather than linked tables.

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject    
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

If fso.FolderExists("[Path to Network Folder]") Then
    ' I'm online
Else
    ' I'm offline
End If
```

Comment: if you can help me out with the codes i will really appreciated it. I need to know how the application checks if there is connection or not to the network, beside that, all the changes made in the laptops must be updated in the server and vice versa.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you have never coded with VBA then you're stuck as you'll need something custom written. If you can code then you'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: thanks Dave, i got it, yes i know how to program in VB. I created the application. it just sometime you run out of ideas, but thanks for your input it helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped! Can you up vote may answer? Thanks! Another method I have used is if the network folder is found, download a 1 Meg file (any file, just make one or get one from the web like I did) and calculate the speed of the download. Time before and time after. Then you will know if the speed is OK or not for communication. This works well if connecting via VPN as sometimes the connection can be too slow and painful for the user.